# Strange irb behaviour, listing content current directory

Tags: ruby, irb

When I paste this code in irb prompt I get listing of current directory after
line `if true`.

```
def some_method()

  if true
        raise StandardError
    end

end
```

Example of output:

```
irb(main):151:0> def some_method()
irb(main):152:1> 
irb(main):153:1*   if true
irb(main):154:2> 
.Skype/                          .m2/                             Desktop/
...
```

I use `irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)` and `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357)`.

Is this a bug, or something else?

Comment: this is very weird. does the session continue to work afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line will have tab characters in it:

```
        raise StandardError
```

`irb` uses `readline` which means that the tab key is used for tab completion.  Double tab will show you all the available options.

To see this in action, just launch `irb` and hit the tab key twice.

See https://superuser.com/questions/37148/how-to-disable-double-tab-to-show-available-commands-in-linux-console for guidance on how to disable it.

Comment: This results in one of the more interesting and esoteric pros of using soft tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the reason Don Cruickshanks mentioned, you should set the option to convert tabs to spaces in your text editor.